# awk with nested if else

Tags: bash, awk, nested-if

I have a tab delimited two column data. I want to get the third based on the condition applied on second column.

if second column is not equal to zero it should print col 1 and 3 and ratio of col1/col2
if col two is zero and col one is more than 15 than it should print col 1 and col2 and the value in col1 (in col 3) else (when col1<=15 & col2 is 0) it should print col1 col2 and 0.

for example, for a file like this

```
1   2
4   5
6   7
14  0
18  0
```

the output should be

```
1   2   0.5
4   5   0.8
6   7   0.85
14  0   0
18  0   18
```

What I have tried:

```
awk '{if ($2!=0) print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $1/$2; elseif($2>15) print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $1 ; else print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $2}'<tags| head
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong, please help me in getting the above code right.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a funny but **unreadable**(maybe) :) one-liner:

```
 awk '{$0=$2?$1FS$2FS$1/$2:$1>15?$1FS$2FS$1:$1FS$2FS"0"}1' file
```

short explaination:

```
a=boolean? first : second

this means assign var a, if boolean true, using value first, otherwise use value second.

I set `$0 = $2? FOO : BAR`
FOO part: $1 FS $2 FS $1/$2
BAR part: $1>15? FOO2 : BAR2
    FOO2 part: $1 FS $2 FS $1
    BAR2 part: $1 FS $2 FS "0"

finally, print $0
```

**Problem in your code**

chang `elseif` -> `else if`  also check `$1` with `15`, not `$2` then your oneliner works too.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different way:

```
awk '{if($2!=0) $3=$1/$2; else if($1>15) $3=$1; else $3=0}1' OFS='\t' file
```

Determined by the order of the if clause:

```
awk '{$3=0} $1>15{$3=$1} $2{$3=$1/$2}1' OFS='\t' file
```

or the cryptic version:

```
awk '{$3=$2?$1/$2:$1>15?$1:0}1' OFS='\t' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative:

```
awk '!$2 { $3 = $1>15 ? $1 : 0 } $2 { $3 = $1/$2 } 1' OFS='\t' CONVFMT='%.2g'
```

Output:

```
1   2   0.5
4   5   0.8
6   7   0.86
14  0   0
18  0   18
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{$3=$1>=15 && $2==0?$1:$1<15 && $2==0?0:$1/$2}1' your_file
```